# Edit DB Rows in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there any way to create a SSRS Report that edit DB Rows?

At the moment i use ssrs to update Row per Row but now i need to change more rows at the same time.

When there are no way, please can you help me, saying what you are using to edit more DB Rows via Webbrowser at the same time?

thx

Comment: Who use ssrs to edit data? Sorry but that's new thing for me..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The query of a dataset can have stored procedures, update statements etc. You can probably even use sp_executesql and supply your query using a parameter.

You can, but you shouldn't.